# connection.commit throws disk I/O error, but *only* when running script via procmail

Tags: django, procmail

I have a Django python script that is supposed to run when an email is received. The email is sent to procmail. The `.procmailrc` file in the user directory looks like this:

```
LOGFILE=debug.log

:0 
* !^FROM_DAEMON 
* !^FROM_MAILER 
* !^X-[-\w]+Loop: .* 
| sudo /path/to/project/process_message.sh
```

The process_message.sh script looks like:

```
DIR=$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )
CONTENTS=$(cat)

cd $DIR
source ./bin/activate
echo -e "$CONTENTS" | ./project/manage.py command_name
```

Important points:

1. The paths appear to be correct. Looking at debug.log, I can see the script is being called.
2. Permissions should not be a problem since process_message is run as root using sudo.
3. Running the process_message.sh works correctly
4. Running the process_message.sh as the email user also works

The error *only* occurs when run through procmail.

Here's the error stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./app/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/path/to/project/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/path/to/project/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/path/to/project/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 393, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/path/to/project/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 444, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/path/to/project/app/communication/management/commands/process_reply.py", line 133, in handle
    self.process_email(email_obj)
  File "/path/to/project/app/communication/models.py", line 37, in from_email_addr
    return self.from_code(code)
  File "/path/to/project/app/communication/models.py", line 41, in from_code
    match = self.get(...)
  File "/path/to/project/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 127, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/path/to/project/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 328, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/path/to/project/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 144, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/path/to/project/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 965, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/path/to/project/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 238, in iterator
    results = compiler.execute_sql()
  File "/path/to/project/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 840, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/path/to/project/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/path/to/project/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/path/to/project/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 97, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/path/to/project/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 658, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/path/to/project/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/path/to/project/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 318, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: disk I/O error
```

Comment: Could you add some debug statements to `manage.py` to see the value of `sys.argv` and probably the contents of the environment?  Also anything else which gets passed down to the lower layers (global variables?)

Comment: As an aside, the shell script is stupendously over-engineered.  All you are doing is `cd $(dirname "$0"); . ./bin/activate; ./project/manage.py command_name` it seems.  The script should probably have a `#!/bin/bash` shebang line (or maybe `#!/bin/sh` once you get rid of the needless bashisms) just to make sure it is being correctly executed.

Comment: Actually that just might be the problem. If `root` executes it with `sh`, `BASH_SOURCE` will not be valid (not sure why you are using that anyway; `$0` seems to be what you are looking for).